# swiperefreshlayout recycler view does not pull down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to implement SwipeRefreshLayout to a RecyclerView. My problem is the that the RecyclerView itself is not pulling down during the refresh gesture. As in, the RecyclerView remains still while i get the refresh icon. Can someone please help me to get the recyclerview to slide down a little for refresh.

Here is the design

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refreshMeeting"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is the expected behavior, though. SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't make the view inside it to be pulled down.

Comment: You have to use some libraries